# GLPI edit/hide fields in existing tabs

Tags: php, frameworks, system

I am using GLPI 9.4.3.
For example in Assets > Computers.
I wanted to change what fields users need to enter, hide unnecessary and add new input fields needed. So far I have searched through the forum and the GUI.

Things tried:
I found that we can add new tabs, for example in Assets > New Stuff, then customize that form through the Object Management.
Or using Additional Fields, I can add new input fields to existing tabs in the Assets menu.
The forum said there is an asset template? I could not even find that Edit Template button.
There is also a FormCreator which seems to only add forms instead of editing the original forms.
There is one talking about creating tickets for support?

I am new to this system, could anyone clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard assets should not be updated manually. Use Fusioninventory instead: http://fusioninventory.org/

You can dive into GLPI forms and edit but doesn't seem like a good idea. When you need to update, and you will, code maintenance is on you and will become a nightmare.

Formcreator is for creating new forms for tickets only. Not assets oriented.

If you need new assets, Generic Object is your plugin: https://plugins.glpi-project.org/#/plugin/genericobject

Other alternatives would require plugin creation. We've built on for a client to inventory trees, and fill VTA :)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Hiding unnecessary fields in existing tabs**
A quick way
Enter glpi/inc, edit corresponding php files for that page. Find it using the page name.
Find the field you want to hide, make td to td hidden
Better way
Fusion inventory

New fields in existing tabs
Use additional fields plugins, link to current tabs. Add new fields

New tabs
Like what Oscar said, use Generic Object. Add objects and fields.

New fields in Generic object new tabs
Edit glpi/plugins/genericobject/fields/field.constant.php
Add new lines per fields
$GO_FIELDS[$item[0]['name'] = __("fieldname");
$GO_FIELDS[$item[0]['field'] = "fieldname";
$GO_FIELDS[$item[0]['input_type'] = "text";